# QR Reader in iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, qr-code

I have one application in which I want to scan QR code + bar codes on food packets for 1 store.  I have tried ZBar reader for bar code scanning.  It is working perfectly.  Now I want to scan QR code also.  For that I have searched and downloaded sample code. But all are not proper.  Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4):

If You want to read **QRCode  use Zbar sdk**

try this

> ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
>
> [scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_QRCODE
>                  config:ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
>                      to:1];

Answer (score 0):

Megha:Zbar SDK is best for bar code and QR Code Scanner
 u have to try this link
https://github.com/a2n/zbar-iphone-example
i have also tried this in My Application and its working perfect.

Comment: I don't want to use zbar .Because it is not giving me proper result.It wants proper lightings ,I can not scan my ID cards in medium light.So i want to use QR Reader..Please help

Comment: SDK provides only idea and base,this logic you have to create own, because,no one have similar requirement Code.Try it yourself.Good Luck!!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are 40 versions of QR code.
I am sure ZDBar SDK scans version 1 QRCode I have used it successfully.Check the documentation to verify the other supproted versions. 
Have yo identified the version of QR codes you want to support ?

Cheers

Comment: No...But Any version that work perfact will be used..Can you suggest?Can you give me code/

Answer (score 0):

i have used this http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/install.html in many of my applications to read qr codes,bar codes,UPC codes sucessfully

Answer (score 0):

[zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) has an iphone port for qr code reading